# I am unable to boot windows 8.1

Tags: bios

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago. Due to some error my hard disk was erased. Now I am trying to install Windows 8.1 again, but I am getting this error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Comment: Do you have a 'Windows installation disc'?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8.1 installation disk, you can try this:

1. Insert Windows 8.1 disk and restart computer. Let the disk open the installation window where you have to select language to install, time and keyboard.
2. After selected the language, press Next.
3. Press Repair your computer.
4. Press Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt.
5. The console will open, and type "bootrec /fixmbr" without the quotes and press Enter.
6. Then you can close console, press back button and press "Turn off your PC".
7. After that you can try to power on your PC and try to install Windows 8.1 again.

This should help you.